# css active class not working for Tabs

Tags: jquery, css, html

Could you help me with this please ?

css active class not working for Tabs

Demo: http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/tab/index-nw2.html

CSS

```
.filter-button
{
        padding: 6px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #fd0009;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fd0009;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.filter-button:hover, .filter-button.active
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #fd0009;
   border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #fd0009;

}
.btn-default.filter-button.active {
    background-color: #fd0009 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Does the demo have anything to do with the problem? if not please paste an actual example of the problem

Comment: Don’t see you setting an `active` class on the buttons in that fiddle ...?

Comment: css cannot the class of an element, you need a javascript to do so.

Comment: Hi Hery, Can you tell me that how to do this by using javascript, please? Kindly share the code If you have any sample for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have a simple problem with your jquery , you writhe the condition outside the click function , thats why the active class didn't added , now thats solved check with snippet run this working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".filter-button").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        
        if(value == "all")
        {
            //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.filter').show('1000');
        }
        else
        {
//            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
//            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
            $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
            $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
            
        }
  $(".filter-button").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    
    
 

});
```

```css
a, a:focus, a:active, * {
    outline:0 !important;
   }
 
   
.gallery-title
{
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #42B32F;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.gallery-title:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 7.5%;
    left: 46.5%;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5e5e5e;
}
.filter-button
{
     padding: 6px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #fd0009;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fd0009;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.filter-button:hover, .filter-button.active
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #fd0009;
   border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #fd0009;

}
.btn-default.filter-button.active {
    background-color: #fd0009 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}
 
      

.port-image
{
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery_product
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.gallery_heading_pan {
 width: 96%;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding: 15px 2%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #333;
 }   
   
   
.image_gly {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.gallery_nf:hover .image_gly {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.gallery_nf:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fd0009;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1 class=""></h1>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button active" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="spray">Spray Nozzle</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="irrigation">Irrigation Pipes</button>
        </div>
        <br>



            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe" style="display: block;"> <a href="http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/tab/index-nw2.html#"><img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

           
            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe" style="display: block;"> <a href="http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/tab/index-nw2.html#"><img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe" style="display: block;"> <a href="http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/tab/index-nw2.html#"><img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;"> 
            <a href="http://dev.ktimes.co/was20378/tab/index-nw2.html#"><img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive"></a>
              <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter irrigation" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe" style="display: block;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter spray" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery_product col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle" style="display: none;">
                <img src="./Bootstrap_files/saved_resource" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="gallery_heading_pan">Heading Text here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
   
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.active` is not getting added to `.filter-button` class try checking your script for issues

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".filter-button").click(function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

            if (value == "all") {
                $('.filter').show('1000');
            }
            else {

                $(".filter").not('.' + value).hide('3000');
                $('.filter').filter('.' + value).show('3000');

                }

               $(".filter-button").removeClass("active");


               $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```